# Lambert series expansion identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have a question which goes like this:

How can I show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{\left(1-z^n\right)^2} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}$$ for $|z|<1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try using the expansions
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\dots
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\dots
$$
**Expansion:**

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)z^{kn+n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^{kn}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty kz^{kn}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty kz^{kn+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{kz^k}{1-z^k}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you expand more on how to use the hints?

Comment: @Chris: Try to plug $x=z^n$ in the $n$th terms of the LHS and of the RHS of the relation you want to prove.

Comment: That was really hard to enter using the mobile interface.

Comment: @Didier: Thanks

Comment: @robjohn: I'm sorry for putting you through the trouble..:) Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Chris: You're welcome. It was my choice to try to answer while away from home. I knew it was not going to be as easy as with a mouse and full keyboard.